# How to pass the location of a php include in the url?

Tags: php

i have a large number of files with several id's in each file.  For example file1.php contains a number of paragraphs, each paragraph has a unique id. (id="1",id="2",id="3" etc...)  I would like the ability to create a link to a page (page A.php) and pass the location of one of these id's in the url of the link to display in a php include on page A.php  The result that i'm looking for is to have the entire file (file1.php) show up inside of page A.php with the specific id that is passed in the url being highlighted.  Is this possible? or do I need to use Java Script and an iframe?

Here is what I ended up with:

```
The url: http://mydomain/thispage.php?xul=http://mydomain.com/folder1/folder2/file.php&id=Abc150:176
```

The code:

```
Stylesheet .vrsehilite{styling}

<script type="text/javascript">var x = <?php echo json_encode($_GET["id"]); ?>;</script>

<?php

$invdmn = "<h2>Error: Invalid Domain</h2>";
$filnf = "<h2>Error: File Not Found</h2>";
$pthinv = "<h2>Error: The Path is invalid</h2>";
$idinv = "<h2>Error: The ID is invalid</h2>";
$oops = "<br/><h2>Oops! Something went wrong.<br/><br/>Please click the back button or use the menu to go to a new page.</h2>";
$testdomain = substr_compare ($_GET['xul'],"http://mydomain.com",0,20,FALSE); //make sure the domain name is correct

if ($testdomain == 0) {
  $flurl = $_GET['xul'];
} else {
  echo $invdmn . " " . $oops;
}

$flurl_headers = @get_headers ($flurl);

if ($flurl_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
  echo $filnf . " " . $oops;  //Make sure the file exist
} else {
  $surl = str_replace (".com/",".com/s/",$flurl);
} //add some characters to url at point to explode

list($url1, $path) = explode ("/s/",$surl); //explode into array of 2 [0]url to domain [1] path
$testpath = substr_compare ($path,"file1/file2/",0,10,FALSE); //make sure the path is correct

if ($testpath == "0") {
  $aid = preg_match ("/^[A-Z][a-z]{2}(?:[1-9][0-9]?|1[0-4][0-9]|150):(?:[1-9][0-9]?|1[0-6][0-9]|17[0-6])$/", $_GET['id']);
} else {    //make sure the id is valid
   echo $pthinv . " " . $oops;
} 

if ($aid == 1) {
  include($path); 
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
  echo "document.getElementById(x).className = 'vrsehilite';";
  echo "document.getElementById(x).scrollIntoView();";
  echo "window.scrollBy(0,-100);";
  echo "</script>";
} else {
  echo $idinv . " " . $oops;
}

?>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place to request code, It is more a place to show your code and have people help you work through issues to find a solution.

Comment: So to answer your question, yes it is possible.

Comment: Ok sorry.  I'm new to php and to this site.  I was able to pass a variable in the url and echo it onto the page, but wasn't sure how to echo it into  the phpinclude   I put in the url like this: http://mysite.php?url=http://locationOfFile1.php#3  I echoed it onto the page using" <?php
 echo "<h1>The url is " . $_GET["url"] . "</h1>";
 ?>

Comment: You use conditional `if` statements, so doing something like `if($_GET['id'] == 1) { show this block of code here}` etc etc. But you really have to sanitize all user input.

Comment: if you need more help just ask :-)

Comment: please put your code in your question, not in the comments

Comment: I would really appreciate it if one of you young guys would take a look at this code now to see if it is sanitized enough to keep out those who might want to insert some malicious code to my site.  This old fogey is just learning php and i'm a little nervous about this based upon the comments made here.  I realize this site is all about points and i'll help you get what ever points I can.  Just let me know what I can do to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Never ever** `include` arbitrary files submitted by the user. Instead, you should only `include` files from a pre-defined set of **your** choice. Perhaps something like this:

#### PHP

```
$files = array ('file1.php', 'file2.php', 'view.php', 'edit.php');
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];

if (isset ($files[$id])) {
  include $files[$id];
} else {
   /* Error */
}
```

Or you could use a regular expression to accept only certain filenames, in this case 1 or more lower case letters followed by 0 or more digits.

```
$m = array ();

if (   preg_match ('#^http://domain.example/folder1/folder2/([a-z]+[0-9]*\\.php)$#', $m)
    && file_exists ($m[1])) {
  include $m[1];
} else {
  /* Page not found */
}
```

You may want to check the return value of include. You may also want to move the folders into the subpattern `(...)` or use regular expressions for the folder names.

---

If all you need is to highlight a certain paragraph in a page, you should add a URL `fragment` that poins to the paragraph's `id`, and add CSS to style it. Eg:

#### URL

`http://domain.example?id=1#p1`

#### HTML

```
<p id=p1>This is the target paragraph.
```

#### CSS

```
p:target { /* Style the targeted <p> element */ }
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I really appreciate it. In this case, there are too many files(31,175) to set up an array for. Perhaps I need to come up with some conditional statements that ensure the root path is from my site? All of the files have the domain and 2 folders in common in their path. http://mydomain/folder1/folder2. Then I could use some code to strip away the domain before inputting the variable into the include statement. Would this be a good plan or is more needed?
I did use the id# to switch the class.

Comment: Ok Thanks, I changed the code in my question. I had gone about it a little differently than what you suggest, but think it does about the same thing?   It does use a relative path.  Should I also check the path against the regex?  The file names are all letters, but of different lengths.  The id's are all in the same format, but also have different lengths. 3letters1-150:1-176  I didn't check to make sure the file exists, because I will be the one writing the links to this page and will check each one as I write the code. Bad links would only cause blank space or errors, right?

Comment: After looking at it again, I think making sure the file exist would be a good idea.  That would ensure it was coming from my site.  My code doesn't really do that.  Someone could simply put my domain in the field and it wouldn't matter because it is stripped away before the include.  I'm not sure how to code this part, but will look it up.  Thanks again.

Comment: I modified the code again.  I think this meets all of your suggestions?  Will I need to worry about someone inserting malicious code to my site with this?

Comment: You need to add a trailing slash when testing the domain name, unless you want something like `http://mydomain.com.otherdomain.com/...` to sail right through. The rest seems overly convoluted and error-prone. My answer remains much the same. Test the url and id using *simple* regexp's, test if the file exists and then include it.

Comment: @rolo: By the way, I would validate the `id` using `preg_match ('/^[a-z]{3}(\d+):(\d+)$/i', $m)`, and then check that each number (`$m[1]`, `$m[2]`) is in range. It just seems much easier on my eyes.

Comment: Ok Thank you.  I figured I had gone about things the long way.  I had a hard time with the regex.  I had to get help with it.